# Vim paragraph autoformatting weird behavior if line ends in comma

Tags: vim

I'm editing an English plain text file and have set `vim` to auto-format paragraphs (insert line breaks as necessary to wrap to text-width 79), as such:

```
:set fo=tna
:set linebreak
:set tw=79
:set wrap
:set breakat=
```

However, this behaves weirdly (adding unwanted indents when the lines ends in commas)

For instance, I expect something like (tw=22 for the sake of example)

```
The quick brown fox,
having run across the
bridge, jumped over a
lazy dog.
```

However, `vim` formats it like:

```
The quick brown fox,
    having run across
    the bridge, jumped
    over a lazy dog.
```

The first line ending in a comma causes the rest of the paragraph to be indented, and I don't know why. Is there any way to turn off this behavior?

Comment: What does `:set filetype` tell about the file ?

Comment: `:set filetype?` says that `filetype=text`